# Why is R inaccurate when performing large tasks on polydigit reals?

Tags: r

I am using R version 2.15.3 (2013-03-01) -- "Security Blanket" on Xubuntu 12.10 3.8.8-030808-generic in RStudio version 0.97.336.

I have written an algorithm which provides a generalized solution to Project Euler's fifth problem:

"2520 is the smallest number that can be divided by each of the numbers from 1 to 10 without any remainder.

What is the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 20"(http://projecteuler.net/problem=5)?

The program keeps finding min=116396280, while the answer is 232792560(2*116396280). Clicking on our test vector shows us that test[16]=7274767.5, however, manually entering `test[16]` brings back 7274768. Additionally when manually entering `identical(test,floor(test))` returns `FALSE`, as it should. Why is it when R is going through these loops that it ignores the fact `7274767.5!=floor(7274767.5)`?

```
pe5<-function(n){
  p<-c()
  for(x in 1:n){
    while(x!=1){
      y<-2
      z<-0
      while(x!=z){
        z<-x/y
        if(z==floor(z)){
          x<-z
          p<-append(p,y)
        }else{
          y<-y+1
        }
      }
    }
  }
  min<-0
  test<-rep(0,n)
  x<-2520
  while(min==0){
    for(i in unique(p)){
      test[i]<-x/i
    }
    if(identical(test,floor(test))==TRUE){
      min<-x
    }else{
      x<-x+2520      
    }
  }
  print(min)
}
pe5(20)
```

Comment: all over my head, of course, but: `116396280 / (1:20)` returns all integers... the 16th of which is 7274768.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6490695/269476

Comment: @timriffe: Check `116396280 / (1:20) - trunc(116396280 / (1:20))`

Comment: It appears that your first loop computes a decomposition into primes for all integers `1:n`. You should be able to compute the desired quantity directly from this decomposition, without the complicated second loop (hint: `rle(p)`).

Comment: over my head too, but if I can give you one piece of advise if you are going to tackle project Euler with R: Make sure you understand the difference between numeric and integers (e.g. when to use `1L` and not `1`) as 1) it will save you a lot of crazy floating numeric nightmares and 2) it will often make the difference between sluggish and smoking fast code. Right now your code is using numerics all over the place and it's a shame.

Comment: As soon as you start using `/` to compute `z` you are coercing to 'double', i.e. not an integer.

Comment: As we all find out sooner or later,  `floor` may well not return the integer you expected, because what's displayed as 3475827532, when of type `double`, is internally something like 3475827531.99999999998213101, and the obvious undesirable happens.  I've used `floor(round(x))` as a workaround.

Comment: @timriffe Increase the number of digits printed (e.g., `options(digits=22)`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is it when R is going through these loops that it ignores the fact `7274767.5!=floor(7274767.5)`?

It doesn't. You never make it check that in these loops.

Let's see what your code does:

```
p<-c()
for(x in 1:n){
  while(x!=1){
    y<-2
    z<-0
    while(x!=z){
      z<-x/y
      if(z==floor(z)){
        x<-z
        p<-append(p,y)
      }else{
        y<-y+1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For each number from 1 to `n` you append its prime factors to `p` (initially empty), each as often as it occurs in the prime factorisation.

So after that, `p` contains all primes `<= n`, some of them multiple times (I think, I don't know R, so I'm not 100% sure that `append()` does what I think it does), the primes larger than `n/2` only once.

```
for(i in unique(p)){
  test[i]<-x/i
}
if(identical(test,floor(test))==TRUE){
  min<-x
}else{
  x<-x+2520      
}
```

For each of the primes listed in `p`, you check whether the current candidate `x` is a multiple of that. If it's not a multiple of one of the primes, you increase `x` by 2520.

Since 2520 is already divisible by all positive integers `<= 10`, you are effectively checking whether a multiple of 2520 is also divisible by 11, 13, 17, and 19.

Now, for a prime `π > 10`, `k*2520` is a multiple of `π` if and only if `k` is a multiple of `π`, so what you compute is

```
2520*11*13*17*19 = 2³ * 3² * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17 * 19
```

You never actually consider prime powers in your algorithm, so you always get `2520 * product of the primes > 10 in the range`. For the upper bound 20, the only number divisible by a higher power of a prime `< 10` than 2520 (or a square of a prime `> 10`) is 16, so that's your only "failure case".

It would have been more obvious if you tested it with a larger bound, for `n = 25` you would have gotten a result too small by a factor of `2*5` [2 from 16, and one 5 from `25 = 5²`], for `n = 27` the result would have been too small by a factor of `2*3*5` [also a 3 from `27 = 3³`].

You need to find the highest power of each prime that doesn't exceed `n`, the result is the product of these prime powers.

Comment: You're right I needed to consider the p-adic order for 10:n of all p<n. Will post a solution soon. Today a professor told me a mark of a skilled R programmer is that (s)he will avoid using loops as much as possible. Can you (or anyone) recommend me some resources/ examples that I may learn from in this regard? I'd especially be interested to see how it might be done in this example. Thanks very much Daniel!

Comment: *the _maximum_ p-adic order

Comment: I don't know R, so I can't recommend resources for that, sorry. Regarding "avoid using loops as much as possible", that is imperfectly phrased (it could be pure cargo cult, but I'll assume the professor meant the right thing, it's more likely). The language offers higher-level abstractions, and a lot of stuff can be expressed shorter and clearer using these abstractions than with manually written loops (the abstractions do the bookkeeping for you, for example). So when there's already a pre-made abstraction doing what you intend, use that instead of reimplementing it for your special case.

Comment: (Not sure whether it's relevant for R, but generally, that rule can be overridden by performance concerns. If you write it yourself, you can tailor the loops to the specific situation, and that, if done well, can perform drastically better. So _if_ you need to do better than the higher-level abstractions, _and_ you can achieve that by writing manual loops, use loops. But speeding up a computation by a factor of, say, 3 is useless if that computation takes just 0.1% of the total time.) Read "as much as possible" as "when there is a better way, and usually there is".

Answer (score 0):

As promised, though a bit delayed, here is a working solution. I went for efficiency of the program, not of the coding, but I bet there is a much shorter way to write an even more efficient script(feel free give suggestions in this regard or post your own solution). I also coded, correct me if I'm wrong, my first bit of artificial intelligence into this program.

```
n<-500
if(!exists("primeslist",mode="numeric")){
    primeslist<-(2)
  }
  q<-matrix(rep(NA,n*floor(log(n,2))),n,floor(log(n,2)))
  for(i in 2:n){
    j<-1
    x<-as.numeric(i)
    while(x!=1){
      k<-1
      y<-primeslist[k]
      z<-1
      while(x!=z){
        z<-x/y
        if(z==floor(z)){
          x<-z
          q[i,j]<-y
          j<-j+1
          if(y>tail(primeslist, 1)){
            primeslist<-append(primeslist, y)
          }
        }else{
          if(tail(primeslist, 1)>y){
            k<-k+1
            y<-primeslist[k]
          }else{
            y<-y+1
          } 
        }
      }
    }
  }
  t<-unique(as.vector(q))
  t<-t[!is.na(t)]
  padicmat<-matrix(rep(0, n*3),n,3)
  padicmat[,1]<-1:n
  for(i in t){
    padicrow<-rep(NA,n)
    for(j in 1:n){
      padicrow[j]<-length(which(q[j,]==as.numeric(i)))
    }
    padicmat[i,2]<-max(padicrow)
  }
padicmat[,3]<-padicmat[,1]^padicmat[,2]
result<-prod(padicmat[,3])
result
```